# imshow does not show the same image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, dicom

I used to use OpenCV in C language, but now decided give MATLAB a chance. I am pretty new to MATLAB and from the first minute I had a problem:

I read the image with:

```
X=dicomread('medicalimage.dcm')
```

but when I displayed the image with imshow(X), the image displayed was not the same with I uploaded even though I did not make any changes on the image. What is the reason for that? There is a pretty obvious contrast difference between the two images and also, it seems like I lost some of the details in the original image.

I am using MATLAB R2010b on my Ubuntu 12.04 system.

```
                      Filename: 'x.dcm'
                   FileModDate: '06-Nov-2006 09:49:26'
                      FileSize: 526966
                        Format: 'DICOM'
                 FormatVersion: 3
                         Width: 512
                        Height: 512
                      BitDepth: 12
                     ColorType: 'grayscale'
FileMetaInformationGroupLength: 202
    FileMetaInformationVersion: [2x1 uint8]
       MediaStorageSOPClassUID: '1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.1.2'
    MediaStorageSOPInstanceUID: '1.3.12.2.1107.5.1.4.54693.30000006100507010800000005302'
             TransferSyntaxUID: '1.2.840.10008.1.2.1'
        ImplementationClassUID: '1.3.6.1.4.1.19291.2.1'
     ImplementationVersionName: 'OSIRIX001'
  SourceApplicationEntityTitle: 'OSIRIX'
          SpecificCharacterSet: 'ISO_IR 100'
                     ImageType: 'ORIGINAL\PRIMARY\AXIAL\CT_SOM5 SPI'
                   SOPClassUID: '1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.1.2'
                SOPInstanceUID: '1.3.12.2.1107.5.1.4.54693.30000006100507010800000005302'
                     StudyDate: '20061005'
                    SeriesDate: '20061005'
               AcquisitionDate: '20061005'
                   ContentDate: '20061005'
                     StudyTime: '101556.921000'
                    SeriesTime: '102051.046000'
               AcquisitionTime: '101818.126639'
                   ContentTime: '101818.126639'
               AccessionNumber: '0'
                      Modality: 'CT'
                  Manufacturer: 'SIEMENS'
               InstitutionName: 'hY9'
            InstitutionAddress: ''
        ReferringPhysicianName: [1x1 struct]
                   StationName: 'CT54693'
              StudyDescription: 'Extrémités inférieures^Pied_cheville_UHR (Adulte)'
         ProcedureCodeSequence: [1x1 struct]
             SeriesDescription: 'Pied/cheville  1.0mm std'
       PerformingPhysicianName: [1x1 struct]
                  OperatorName: [1x1 struct]
         ManufacturerModelName: 'Sensation 64'
       ReferencedStudySequence: [1x1 struct]
       ReferencedImageSequence: [1x1 struct]
           SourceImageSequence: [1x1 struct]
                   PatientName: [1x1 struct]
                     PatientID: 'vAD7q3'
              PatientBirthDate: ''
                    PatientSex: ''
                    PatientAge: '000Y'
              BodyPartExamined: 'EXTREMITY'
                SliceThickness: 1
                           KVP: 120
        DataCollectionDiameter: 500
            DeviceSerialNumber: '54693'
               SoftwareVersion: 'syngo CT 2006A'
                  ProtocolName: 'Pied_cheville_UHR'
        ReconstructionDiameter: 206
      DistanceSourceToDetector: 1040
       DistanceSourceToPatient: 570
            GantryDetectorTilt: 0
                   TableHeight: 95
             RotationDirection: 'CW'
                  ExposureTime: 1000
               XrayTubeCurrent: 110
                      Exposure: 122
                    FilterType: '0'
                GeneratorPower: 17
                     FocalSpot: 0.7000
         DateOfLastCalibration: '20061005'
         TimeOfLastCalibration: '073350.000000'
             ConvolutionKernel: 'U30u'
               PatientPosition: 'FFS'
              StudyInstanceUID: '2.16.840.1.113669.632.20.1211.10000315526'
             SeriesInstanceUID: '1.3.12.2.1107.5.1.4.54693.30000006100507010800000005268'
                       StudyID: 'A10025547593'
                  SeriesNumber: 5
             AcquisitionNumber: 3
                InstanceNumber: 34
          ImagePositionPatient: [3x1 double]
       ImageOrientationPatient: [6x1 double]
           FrameOfReferenceUID: '1.3.12.2.1107.5.1.4.54693.30000006100506302075000001028'
                 SliceLocation: 58
                 ImageComments: 'JPEG 2000 lossless - Version 4.0.2 (c) Image Devices GmbH'
               SamplesPerPixel: 1
     PhotometricInterpretation: 'MONOCHROME2'
                          Rows: 512
                       Columns: 512
                  PixelSpacing: [2x1 double]
                 BitsAllocated: 16
                    BitsStored: 12
                       HighBit: 11
           PixelRepresentation: 1
       SmallestImagePixelValue: 0
        LargestImagePixelValue: 2583
                  WindowCenter: [2x1 double]
                   WindowWidth: [2x1 double]
              RescaleIntercept: -1024
                  RescaleSlope: 1
  WindowCenterWidthExplanation: 'WINDOW1\WINDOW2'
             RequestingService: 'Service d'orthopédie pédiatri'
 RequestedProcedureDescription: 'CT pied-cheville'
RequestedProcedureCodeSequence: [1x1 struct]
     RequestAttributesSequence: [1x1 struct]
```

On the left there is the output of imshow and on the right, there is the original image: http://img23.imageshack.us/img23/3166/differencem.png?http://imageshack.us/

Result of imshow(X,[0 255]) : http://img248.imageshack.us/img248/4140/difference2.png?http://imageshack.us/

Link to my DCM image: http://www.speedyshare.com/7enTP/x.dcm.zip

Answer (score 2):

If your DICOM data contains a colormap, then you should import it too using a second output to `dicomread` and apply it to the image using the second argument of `imshow`. Example:

```
[X, map] = dicomread('US-PAL-8-10x-echo.dcm');
imshow(X(:,:,1,1),map)
```

[image]

Comment: I checked DICOM info and it does not contain a colormap unfortunately.You can check the difference from this link: (on the right it is the original image, on the left there is the image which imshow shows) http://img23.imageshack.us/img23/3166/differencem.png?http://imageshack.us/

Comment: Please upload the data file you're using. We can't tell much without that. You can try using `imcontrast` and adjusting the levels manually...

Comment: Host it somewhere (there are millions of free sites out there) and share the link

Comment: sorry for the delay. here is the link to the image: http://www.speedyshare.com/7enTP/x.dcm.zip

Comment: Did you have time to check the file?

Comment: @Amadeus Your original image has the contrast levels adjusted heavily (in whatever software you viewed it) and you will have to reproduce that in MATLAB. If you do `imagesc(x);colormap(gray);`, it produces a crisper image than `imshow`. Now do `imcontrast` and it should popup a histogram with some controls. Try playing around with those — moving things further to the left seems to get it close to your original.

Answer (score 1):

`imshow` scales the intensity of the image based on the minimum & maximum intensity. Assuming the max intensity is 255, try `imshow(X,[0 255]);`.

Comment: I think my problem is not related to that. On the right there is the original image, on the left there is the image with imshow(X,[0,255]) http://img248.imageshack.us/img248/4140/difference2.png?http://imageshack.us/

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried supplying DICOM info as mentioned in the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/dicomread.html)?

```
info = dicominfo('medicalimage.dcm');
Y = dicomread(info);
figure, imshow(Y);
imcontrast;
```

Comment: @I added the DICOM info to my question. imcontrast does not exactly solve my problem.

Comment: The other possibility is that you need a greyscale version of the lines colormap. Looks like open CV used a colormap that enhances the intensity differences between close pixel values rather than using a functional relationship between intensity and value.

Comment: Or to try histogram equalization?

Comment: I do not know how MATLAB works, but I only upload the image and then try to show it. How can OpenCV do such a thing and how can I prevent this situation to occur?

Answer (score 1):

DICOM information has a high dynamic range.  The header for your image says that it's 12-bit data.  You'll need to set a window center and window width for the part of the dynamic range that shows the features of interest to you and compute the minimum and maximum pixel values that correspond to that window setting.  Once you've determined these values, the code below will display the image using that portion of the dynamic range.

```
imshow(img, [minPixelValue, maxPixelValue]);
```